# Currently using two modes of authentication (Basic and OpenIDConnect) need to decide where to route the logic

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, token, basic-authentication, azure-api-management

I am using service fabric, APIM and some policies in the APIM Inbound/outbound.
Just have the following questions where I am really not clear, please help me.

My API is going to call a third party API which is secured by OAuth 2.0

1. Where to store the logic of whether should I use the OAuth 2.0 endpoint or should I proceed with basic based on the university ID. (I have a few universities that use basic for their APIs where I supply username and password while some universities now ask me to do OAuth so need to support that). Should I have this in Service fabbric level? whats the best approach? Maybe I think I should have a config in code here where university IDs and a flag IsOAuth true/false?
2. Any POC code that shows how to obtain a bearer token oAuth 2.0 please? from a API I build and wit a token provider for my POC? Preferably oAuth 2.0 token.

Answer (score 1):

1. This can be done in APIM provided client request carries enough information for you to make that decision. See choose policy, it allows you to have conditional logic and apply different behavior based on client request.
2. OAuth is mostly tailored towards interaction with end user because majority of flows operate with concept of a browser and that would imy that APIM receives bearer token from client. If you want to implement service to service authentication you can do so using send-request policy.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies

Comment: thank you, I am seeing the choose policy in the link above. But dont you think its overloading the API policies and APIM? Is it not better to create this as a service fabric API?

Comment: From APIM point of view this is one of intended use cases. Doing that at APIM layer will simplify your Service Fabric back and as you won't need to worry about authentication there. But there may be valid reasons to have authentication on backend as well. It's your decision.

Comment: Can I have a version 2 of the current api which has policies set for basic and I can set policy of only Oauth in version 2? Is that possible? I mean version one has policy with only basic and version two has policy with oauth only